# Disable only 2 weeks from today in Datepicker 1.6.4?

Tags: datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker, disable

I am setting up specific Datepicker where **only and always next 14 days from today** should be disabled.
I have tried beforeShowDay but it's not working for this.
I have also tried using maxDate, minDate, startDate but in this case, it is not working as all dates in past and in future should be able to be selected **excluding** weekends and 14 days from today.

This is my code for now.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
          $('.datetime').datepicker({
                weekStart: 1,
                clearBtn: true,
                daysOfWeekDisabled: "0,6",
                daysOfWeekHighlighted: "1,5",
                todayHighlight: true


          //format: 'mm/dd/yyyy'
          });
         </script>
```

[Datepicker Image (assuming today is 16th of April, days in red (always days from today) should be disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCX7b.png)